# Stripe Terminal iOS SDK - Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I just recently update stripe terminal iOS SDK to 3.3.1

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-ios/releases

Stripe documentation states:

https://docs.stripe.com/terminal/payments/connect-reader?terminal-sdk-platform=ios&reader-type=bluetooth

```
let connectionConfig = BluetoothConnectionConfiguration(locationId: "{{LOCATION_ID}}")
Terminal.shared.connectBluetoothReader(selectedReader, delegate: readerDelegate, connectionConfig: connectionConfig) { reader, error in
    if let reader = reader {
        print("Successfully connected to reader: \(reader)")
    } else if let error = error {
        print("connectBluetoothReader failed: \(error)")
    }
}
```

When I implement the code below I am getting the error: "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" from xCode.

```
let connectionConfig = BluetoothConnectionConfiguration(locationId: "{{LOCATION_ID}}")
```

[image]

It seems like the new sdk update does not support the current stripe documentation listed on their website and im not sure how to set up the BluetoothConnectionConfiguration with connectionConfig

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the input models now have builders that are required to generate the input. So for this case it should be:

```
    let connectionConfig
do {
    connectionConfig = try BluetoothConnectionConfigurationBuilder(locationId: "...").build()
} catch {
    // handle error
    return
}
// valid connection config to use
...
```

reference: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-ios/issues/290